# I have error while I'm trying to save winforms textboxes values into a connected MS access database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created winform project and bound MS Access database to it, I have created dataGridView which its dataSource is from MS Acess database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwiP5.png)

I also have created 3 textboxes as to carry data inputs and created **"add button"** to save textboxes values into MS Access database and show these data in the dataGridView.

This is the "**add button**" code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string firstName = textBox1.Text;
        string secondName = textBox2.Text;
        int age =Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        int ID = 0;
        ID += 1;

        theDatabase1DataSet.Table1.Rows.Add(ID, firstName, 
          secondName, age);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Inputs have been saved");
    }
```

When I enter text in the textboxes and click on "**add button**"

This error message appears " **System.ArgumentException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in age Column.  Expected type is Int32.'**"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH6gS.png)

Comment: What’s the value of textBox3.Text?

Comment: `age` can't be a string.  Make it an integer.  Use `int.TryParse` to convert.

Comment: @viveknuna I converted textbox3 value from string to int, and the error still appears.

Comment: @MohamedRezk what’s the value? Is it valid int?

Comment: @viveknuna the value of textbox3 is number represents the age of the user. I think the problem in ID column of the database which is cannot be repeated as it's unique but I can't skip adding values to the ID cells when I click on "add button".

Comment: Mohamed, you have two errors. One with age, which could be if you leave textbox3.text empty. The other issue you have is that ID will always be equals to 1. Move the `int ID = 0;` line to outside the method so it becomes a module-level variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a reason that’s why SO moderators say you should not put the links, rather than put the text , so that it can be easily readable by others.

In your case the main issue was in the attached link and what you have mentioned in the question is completely different.

I have few suggestions for you. You should make the `ID` as primary key of the table and make it autoincrement identity. There’s is no need of explicitly passing the `ID` column then.

About your error your are always inserting value 1 for the `ID` column and it’s giving error because it’s unique.

Comment: may I didn't describe what I want correctly. But I want when I click on the "add button", a new row in the database is being created and I want to add the values of the textboxes to these columns of the newly created row "first name, second name and age" and don't add anything to "ID column". If you understand what I want, Could you suggest me the right code to do this?